# Python Dataframe: clean data of one column by comparing values from other columns

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

Another challenging question for me but perhaps an easy one for you. I just don't know how to think in a pythony way;

I have a data frame:

```
dt={'Name':['A','A','B','B','C','D','D'],'FG':['N','Y','N','Y','N','N','N'], 'Date':[2016,2017,2017,2016,2017,2017,2017]}
```

df=pd.DataFrame(data=dt,columns=['Name','FG', 'Date'])

What I want to do is, for each name in "Names" (which can be repetitive) check the flag value in "FG", if that is set to "Y" and the date associated with that is greater than the one associated with "N" I will keep the entry otherwise I will drop it. I cannot really think of a way to write this code simply due to lack of experience. To visualize here is what I have

```
Name  FG  Date
A     N   2016
A     Y   2017
B     N   2017
B     Y   2016
C     Y   2017
D     N   2017
D     N   2017
```

Here is what I would like to return

```
Name  FG  Date
A     Y   2017
C     Y   2017
```

Thanks heaps guys

Comment: Name  FG  Date
A     N   2016
A     Y   2017
B     N   2017
B     Y   2016
C     Y   2017
D     N   2017
D     N   2017
E     Y   2017
E     N   2017    
And the expected output is
Name  FG  Date
A     Y   2017
C     Y   2017

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add one more column restore the `max` value within the group.

```
df['check']=df.groupby('Name').Date.transform('max')
df.loc[(df.check==df.Date)&(df.FG=='Y'),:]
Out[786]: 
  Name FG  Date  check
1    A  Y  2017   2017
4    C  Y  2017   2017
```

EDIT:

```
mask=df.groupby('Name').\
  apply(lambda x : (x.FG=='Y')&(x.Date>min(x.Date)) if len(x.Date)>1 else (x.FG=='Y')).values

df[mask]
Out[808]: 
  Name FG  Date
1    A  Y  2017
4    C  Y  2017
```

Data input

```
df
Out[809]: 
  Name FG  Date
0    A  N  2016
1    A  Y  2017
2    B  N  2017
3    B  Y  2016
4    C  Y  2017
5    D  N  2017
6    D  N  2017
7    E  Y  2017
8    E  N  2017
```

Comment: Thanks Wen. Just one more question. Your method works fine if the Date values are smaller or greater than each other. If the dates are equal I do not want to keep a record. Example: Add two extra row like this (E,Y,2016) and (E,N,2016). Is there any tweak in the code to filter this out?

Comment: @Omido if it is duplicate  you want to drop them all ?

Comment: I have used drop-duplicate in the code but I guess it has to be based on the Date. So if the date for each name that associates with "N" is greater than or equal to the one with "Y" status, I would like to drop the row associated with "Y". Does this make sense?

Comment: @Omido should it be a new question?LOL

Comment: @Omido If you can provide the sample data, and expected output I think I can help

Comment: Oh I thought there might be a way to modify this? I don't really know how things work in stack overflow. If you think I should post a new one I will

Comment: @Omido  either way work for me , Just need the expected output

Comment: @Omido Just found I answered another question from you before LOL

Comment: { Name  FG  Date
    A     N   2016
    A     Y   2017
    B     N   2017
    B     Y   2016
    C     Y   2017
    D     N   2017
    D     N   2017
    E     Y   2017
    E     N   2017 }   
And the expected output is
    "Name  FG  Date
    {A     Y   2017
    C     Y   2017}

Comment: Yeah your responses are great. It will be the same output as I originally posted. However, the dataset contains two extra rows with Date similar where one FG  is set to "Y" and one is set to "N"